# Most bandwidth efficient setup for video sharing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn, video

I built a video sharing platform for a popular french podcast I contribute to.

- **Initially I used S3 and linked directly to it, bad idea.**
- **Then I used a `pull CDN` to better optimize my bandwidth, but s3 is still solicited a lot.**
- Now I'm compressing video better (from 1.7gb to 400mb each) which should help but I still think it's going to cost a lot monthly and it's voluntary so I'd like the cost to be as minimal as possible.

So now I'm thinking about using a `push CDN` and upload my content there but I'm worried about the storage costs. Would that be a good idea?

Every morning when I put the new show up, it gets about 2000 requests which cost about 100$ of S3 data transfer so far. I'm looking for the cheapest way to host video and share it (bandwidth).

Any suggestions would be very welcome, thanks.

Comment: A youtube channel is one option used by a fair number of video podcasters.

Comment: AWS is great for a lot of things, but not for high bandwidth low budget content distribution. Using a server/VPS from a traditional provider with an unmetered connection as your CDN source is probably something to consider (even if your originals are still stored in S3).